# Date and time plot from .csv in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

i would like to plot a chart with date and time on the orizontal axis and integer value on the vertical axis.
The data I have is in a .csv format, see the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y9zGtbaGwKA4b7DR10fp93GiCNWI0SKj/view?usp=sharing).

I tried with

```
db = Dataset[
  Flatten[Import[
    "C:\\Users\\Matteo\\AppData\\Roaming\\MetaQuotes\\Terminal\\\
C10F84FF203255BEE7679EDC837848E1\\MQL4\\Files\\Data\\date_box.csv"]]]

DateListPlot[db]
```

but it turns out errors:

```
"The first two levels of \
{$Failed,$Failed,$Failed,$Failed,$Failed,$Failed,$Failed,$Failed,$\<<9951>>} cannot be transposed. "

Unable to automatically determine horizontal coordinates for the \
given data and DataRange.

"\!\(TraditionalForm\`{\"2018.02.02 21:59;0\", \"2018.02.02 \
21:59;0\", \"2018.02.02 21:58;0\", ...\) is not a \
valid dataset or list of datasets."
```

i can't fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = Import["C:\\Users\\Matteo\\...\\Files\\Data\\date_box.csv"];
d2 = StringSplit[#, ";"] & /@ Flatten[data];
t = DateList /@ d2[[All, 1]];
i = ToExpression /@ Last /@ d2;
DateListPlot[Transpose[{t, i}]]
```

[image]

***Removing the weekend***

```
days = Take[#, 3] & /@ t;
union = {#, DateString[#, "DayNameShort"]} & /@ Union[days]
```

Looks like you have some data points on Sunday

```
sundaypos = Position[days, {2018, 1, 28}];
Extract[i, sundaypos]
```

Deleting them

```
tnew = Delete[t, sundaypos];
inew = Delete[i, sundaypos];
```

Plotting with an adjustment to eliminate the weekend

```
t1 = AbsoluteTime[{2018, 1, 24}];
t2 = AbsoluteTime[{2018, 1, 27}];
t3 = AbsoluteTime[{2018, 1, 29}];

a = AbsoluteTime /@ tnew;
a2 = If[# >= t2, # - (t3 - t2), #] & /@ a;

labels = {AbsoluteTime[First[#]], Last[#]} & /@
   DeleteCases[union, {{2018, 1, 28}, "Sun"}];
labels[[All, 1]] = If[# >= t2, # - (t3 - t2), #] & /@
   labels[[All, 1]];

ListLinePlot[Sort@Transpose[{a2, inew}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {labels, None}}]
```

[image]

**Version 3**

```
{t1, t2, t3, t4, t5} = AbsoluteTime /@ {{2018, 1, 24},
    {2018, 1, 26, 22, 0, 0}, {2018, 1, 28, 22, 0, 0},
    {2018, 2, 2, 22, 0, 0}, {2018, 2, 4, 22, 0, 0}};

a = AbsoluteTime /@ t;
a2 = Which[
     # >= t4, # - (t3 - t2) - (t5 - t4),
     # >= t2, # - (t3 - t2),
     True, #] & /@ a;

labels = {AbsoluteTime[#],
     DateString[#, {"MonthNameShort", " ", "Day", "\n00:00"}]} & /@
   Append[DeleteCases[union,
      {{2018, 1, 28}, "Sun"}], {{2018, 2, 5}, "Mon"}][[All, 1]];

labels[[All, 1]] = Which[
     # >= t4, # - (t3 - t2) - (t5 - t4),
     # >= t2, # - (t3 - t2),
     True, #] & /@ labels[[All, 1]];

ListPlot[Sort@Transpose[{a2, i}], Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {labels, None}},
 Epilog -> {Dashed, Gray, Line[{{t2, 100}, {t2, -800}}],
   Line[{{t4 - (t3 - t2), 100}, {t4 - (t3 - t2), -800}}]},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: I have a question, if i define `i = ToExpression /@ d2[[All, 2]];` instead of the way you represented, it works. The difference is only in the syntax?

Comment: @perjliv Yes, they both do the same thing.

Comment: I noticed that `DateListPlot` includes also weekends, even if they are not included in my .csv file. I tried with `ListLinePlot[Transpose[{t, i}]]` instead of `DateListPlot` but it does not work... do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @perjliv I have added a solution which could be expanded for a longer data series.

Comment: By the way, there is a dedicated Mathematica site here : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Actually I have some data in sunday evening, and some data in friday evening (from 22:00 to 23:59) are skipped. 
It should conserve the sunday data and simply plot without joining all data in the .csv, reserving one point per data in the graphic. It should not be more simple than the code above?

Comment: Something like the output using `ListLinePlot[i]`, but withe datetime in the x-axis instead of the integers

Comment: @perjliv I have posted another version.  That should show you all you need to extend the idea.